# Как в Visual Studio добавить сразу несколько папок и файлов?

Tags: visual-studio

Хочу перенести папки и файлы с классами в другой проект. Как это сделать, что бы не создавать папки в ручную в обозревателе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто перетащить `DragAndDrop` - тогда они оп-моему переместяться или `ctrl+c ctrl+v` - тогда копируются

Comment: Да Ctrl+С +V помогло а dragAndDrop не работает